# Difference in frame rates of normal and peripheral vision

Tags: eyes

I recently encountered an incident in my laboratory. It was evening and the sunlight entered the lab through a window with exhaust fans. So the ray kept flickering at fixed intervals.

I noticed that the flickering was more noticeable when it was viewed through the side of my eyes.

Is it a fact that the frame rates of the two visions are different?

Comment: Vision doesn't have frame rates.

Comment: I believe the persistence of vision puts an upper limit for the no. of distinct images that can be seen in a second. That is what I meant by the frame rate of vision of human eyes.